# Как поменять ключ во всех массивах

Tags: php

Изучаю PHP, есть задание: реализовать функцию `function($num){}`, где `$num` – массив положительных чисел, количество элементов кратно `3`.
Результат ее выполнение: двумерный массив (массив состоящий из ассоциативных массива с ключами `a`, `b`, `c`).
Пример для входных массива:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

результат

```
[['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'с' => 3],
 ['a' => 4, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 6]]
```

```html
<?php
$num = 5;
function createTrapez($num)
$keys = array('a','b','c');
$arr = array();
$arr = range(0, $num);
$ct = count($arr);
if(($ct%3==0)&&($a>=0))
{
 $values = array_chunk($arr, 3);
foreach ($values as $item =>$array) {
    ${"array{$item}"} = $array;
$c = array_combine($keys, $array);
print_r($c);
}
 else 
echo "Количество элемнтов не кратно 3 или числа отрицательно";
}
?>
```

Происходит замена ключей только в последнем массиве, как сделать, чтобы ключи поменялись во всех массивах?

Comment: 1. `${"array{$item}"}` - это ужас. Используйте один результирующий массив типа `$ret = []; $ret[$items] = ...` - так и по условию задачи правильно. 2. `$arr = array(); $arr = range(0, $num);` - ужас, первая строка не нужна. 3. Ваша функция не возвращает значение.

Answer (score 1):

просто бейте на 3 и соединяйте с ключами.

```
$data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ;

$result = array_map(function($v){
                 return array_combine(['a','b','c'], $v);
             }, array_chunk($data, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

var_dump(fun($array));

function fun($array){
    if(count($array) % 3 !== 0){
        return false;
    }
    $arrays = array_chunk($array, 3);
    $array_keys = ["a", "b", "c"];
    $new_array = [];

    foreach($arrays as $array){
        $new_array[] = array_combine($array_keys, $array);
    }

    return $new_array;
}
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(1)
    ["b"]=>
    int(2)
    ["c"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(4)
    ["b"]=>
    int(5)
    ["c"]=>
    int(6)
  }
}
```